# How to say something happened one hour back

Tags: past-tense, time

I wanted to say that someone went out one hour before the current time, can I say it as "he went out one hour back", or does it sound awkward?

Comment: An hour ago. Ago is the standard term for this.

Comment: @Xanne One went out one hour *ago*, true, but one turns a clock one hour *back*. I think this merits a discussion.

Comment: @MicahWindsor The  OP asked about something that happened an hour before now, not about turning clocks back.

Comment: @KateBunting I just thought it might be a good idea to clarify the meaning and proper usage of "one hour back", especially since OP may (or may not) be an ELL.

Answer (score 1):

"He went out one hour ago."

The definition of "ago" is "Before the present" or "Before now." Therefore, "He went out one hour ago" means the same thing as "He went out one hour before now."